# Monitor continuosly if device is connected over IP

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, ip

I have an electronic device which is connected to the computer over LAN. I have it's SDK to communicate with it.

Before communicating with the device it must be connected and registered with code provided in SDK. That's all fine.

My win application connects and registers the machine when the application starts up, but the problem is if the electronic device is SWITCHED OFF and then SWITCHED ON, the application must again connect and register the device.

So the question is how to continuously monitor if the device is connected over IP (something like PINGING it via C# code).

So one problem while constantly PINGing the device is that I must run it on separate thread, so that it doesn't affect my actual application.  Another good solution would be if I get some piece code which fires event when the device is disconnected over IP.

Thanks for help.
Regards,

**EDIT 1: Some piece of code which I use to connect using SDK**

```
bool connected;
connected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.168.1.201", "4370");

bool registered;
registered = axCZKEM1.RegEvent(1, 65535);
```

**EDIT 2: I am trying the method from answer by sa_ddam213, but I never get a ping failure. Also, it makes my PC run slow. What error am I making ?**

```
while (true)
{
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        ping.PingCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
              if(e.Reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
              {
                   connected=false;
                   registered=false;

                   while(connected && registered)
                   {
                       connected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.168.1.201", 4370);
                       registered = axCZKEM1.RegEvent(1, 65535);
                    }
               }
          };

          ping.Send("192.168.1.201", 3000);
}
```

Comment: If the SDK requires you to "reconnect and re-register" when the device comes offline and online, then it presumably puts your application in a bad state. Can you application code just detect that it's in a bad state and then go back to trying to reconnect?

Comment: Also, it would help if you could tell a little bit more about the device and what ports it listens on.  Can you you "ping" it's IP address from the command line?  Does it have an embedded web server?

Comment: It is a fingerprint Time and Attendance machine, which I use to record attendance when user places finger on it. Yes we can Ping it from command line. It doesn't have any web server embedding in it.

Comment: That will be running slow because you have an Async call in a while loop, that will be sending a LOT of Ping requests

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I changed it to a sync call, but still it doesn't go inside the if loop when device is disconnected!

Comment: perhaps you should create a `System.Threading.Timer` to handle the ping check, and set a `Timeout` a litte less that the time it takes for your device to reboot (switched on, switched off)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `Ping` using c#,

```
 PingReply reply = new Ping().Send("127.0.0.1");
 if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
 {
    // yay
 }
```

Async method:

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
ping.PingCompleted += (sender, e) => 
{
    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        // yay
    }
};
ping.SendAsync("127.0.0.1", 3000, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please refer the edit2, I am unable to get PING failure !